# I want to change background of div onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to get clicked image as background of `div`? I new to `javascript`. I tried using `onclick` but the code did not work.I hope may be due to programming mistakes.

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
<div id="containerA">
<div id="one" ><img src="https://stepupandlive.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/3d-animated-frog-image.jpg" id="image" onclick="change();"/></div>


function change(){
document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = this('src');
};
```

Comment: add relevant codes, html, css, js, etc. whatever you have tried, right or wrong, feel free to share with us..

Comment: I think you should try `this.src` or `this.attr('src')` instead of `this('src')`

Comment: <div id="one" ><a><img src="" id="image" onclick="javascript:change();"/></a></div>.

Comment: you want to change the background of which div???

Comment: the one with id canvas

Comment: Why someone changed the original question?

Comment: Check out my new answer it is working for me!

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this -

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
<div id="containerA">
<div id="one" ><img src="https://stepupandlive.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/3d-animated-frog-image.jpg" id="image" onclick="change(this);"/></div> // passed this to the parameter


function change(obj){
document.getElementById("canvas").style.backgroundImage = obj.src; // here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared a function, but you didn't ask it to run. Try [this](http://jsbin.com/juceho/edit?html,css,js,output) or the code snippet below. Also, you can separate codes in order to control well.

```js
function changeImg() {
  document.getElementById("canvas").style.background = "url('//stephboreldesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/lorem-ipsum-logo.jpg')"
}

document.getElementById("canvas").onclick = changeImg;
```

```css
#canvas { /* just for test, you can change by yourself */
  width: 325px;
  height: 325px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

And [here on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lopado/edit?html,css,js,output) is another version if you'd like to change the background between two images, or more. Below are some references for you to know more about function used in example.

[W3C School - style change](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp), [W3C School - onclick event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

[MDN - style change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), [MDN - onclick event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` to the `onclick` function like this

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
 <div id="containerA">
 <div id="one" ><img src="https://stepupandlive.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/3d-animated-frog-image.jpg" id="image" onclick="change(this);"/></div>
</div>
```

And this is what you do in the Javascript function

```
function change(img){
  var urlString = 'url(' + img.src + ')';
  document.getElementById("canvas").style.backgroundImage =urlString;
};
```

**And this should definitely work!**

Answer (score 0):

1.you didnt added Jquery
2. On click of image you are calling "change" method but you have to correct the method name.

In below image check the red rectangles for errors-

[image]

Comment: OP doesn't want to use jQuery. Pure JS.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use jQuery in your project. With jQuery something like this could work:

```
var imageSource = "";

$("#img").click(function(){
   imageSource = $(this).attr("src");
   $('#canvas').css("background-image", "url("+imageSource+")");  
});
```

Comment: There's no jQuery tag, and not really enough information from which to derive a realistic/practicable solution. While I appreciate your attempt to help I have to suggest that you jumped in too quickly and with the (common) misconception that JavaScript === jQuery.

Comment: @kovogel you have a syntax error on the second last line of your code, you are missing a `)` before the semicolon

Comment: @DavidThomas I understand the objections but at the start post there was no shared code. I added a explanation that jQuery is needed for my example.

Comment: what is img used there?can you please explain

Comment: Right now something with an "img" as id is clickable. If you remove the "#" its for every image tag.

Answer (score -1):

```
function changeImage(imgObj){
       bgImage = imgObj.src;
       $("#updateDiv").css('background-image','url('+bgImage+')');
 }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RL7T0a?p=preview

Comment: Did you go through the demo? I believe you were looking for the same.

Comment: i m using internet explorer

Comment: i tried the demo in IE-11 and it's working there. can you tell me what version your are using?

Comment: Its not working when i am embedding this code to my program.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fxkqcz55/ I have created this fiddle.Could you please check why its not working.